# Launching an activity from an activity other than main

Tags: android, eclipse

My android app will contain three activities for the purpose of this question. The first is `Main`, then, `FishActivity`, and lastly `AnthiasActivity`. I am using buttons to launch these activities. I am able to launch `FishAcivity` from `Main`, however when I use similar code I cannot launch `AnthiasActivity` from `FishActivity`. The app force closes and states "Unfortunately, Reef Fish Guide has stopped. I get no errors in eclipse though.

Edit: Note: when I remove the intent to launch "AnthiasActivity" from "fishActivity", Fish Activity runs fine(just not able to launch next activity). However when I add the code into Fish Activity to launch AnthiasActivity, "FishActivity" won't launch at all.

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button fishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fish);
    fishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     FishActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    Button coralButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.coral);
    coralButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoralActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    Button invertsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inverts);
    invertsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, InvertsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

FishActivity

```
public class FishActivity extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fish);

    Button anthiasButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anthiasButton);
    anthiasButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(FishActivity.this,     AnthiasActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);

        }
    });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

protected Context getActivity(FishActivity fishActivity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fish, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fish, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

AnthiasActivity

```
public class AnthiasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anthias);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anthias, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anthias,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kdc.reeffishguide"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.FishActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fish" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.CoralActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coral" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.InvertsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inverts" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.kdc.reeffishguide.AnthiasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_anthias" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Edit:
Logcat

```
04-18 10:22:41.467: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:22:41.687: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.300000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 67
04-18 10:22:41.687: E/MP-Decision(2162): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
04-18 10:22:41.988: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:1.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 22
04-18 10:22:41.988: E/MP-Decision(2162): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:190.000000
04-18 10:22:44.150: E/Watchdog(923): !@Sync 154
04-18 10:22:45.481: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:22:45.671: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:4.300000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 25
04-18 10:22:45.671: E/MP-Decision(2162): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:145.000000
04-18 10:22:45.972: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:0.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 17
04-18 10:22:45.972: E/MP-Decision(2162): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:195.000000
04-18 10:22:49.485: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:22:53.479: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:22:57.483: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:23:00.155: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:3.200000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 29
04-18 10:23:00.155: E/MP-Decision(2162): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:145.000000
04-18 10:23:00.846: E/MP-Decision(2162): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:1.500000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 11
04-18 10:23:00.846: E/MP-Decision(2162): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:0.000000
04-18 10:23:01.487: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:23:05.481: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(11564): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
04-18 10:23:08.163: E/SmartFaceManager(923): checkForSmartStay S
04-18 10:23:08.163: E/SmartFaceService(923): setValue, key: smart-stay-framecount-reset value: 
04-18 10:23:08.163: E/SmartFaceService(923): register:4668116
04-18 10:23:08.173: E/SmartFaceService.Client(923): New SmartFaceService.Client, service type: 100 pid: 923
04-18 10:23:08.193: E/CameraController(923): Wait for 1
04-18 10:23:08.193: E/CameraController(923): handleMessage: { what=1 when=-3ms arg1=4 }
04-18 10:23:08.213: E/SecCamera-JNI-Java(923): SecCamera.open()
04-18 10:23:08.213: E/CameraController(923): open() as 100
04-18 10:23:08.223: E/SecCamera-JNI-Java(923): SecCamera()
04-18 10:23:08.223: E/CameraService(370): system_server
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): CameraService::connect before lock (pid 923, org id 11)
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): orgID: 3 checkingID: 0 seems GOOD
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): orgID: 3 checkingID: 1 seems GOOD
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): orgID: 3 checkingID: 2 seems GOOD
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): orgID: 3 checkingID: 3 seems GOOD
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/CameraService(370): orgID: 3 checkingID: 4 seems GOOD
04-18 10:23:08.233: E/QualcommCamera(370): Qint android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
04-18 10:23:08.313: E/SecCameraCoreManager(370): !@ cam: CaMeRa(3)
04-18 10:23:08.313: E/SecCameraCoreManager(370): initialize1
04-18 10:23:08.313: E/QualcommCamera(370): int android::camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**): start : 1
04-18 10:23:08.313: E/mm-camera-intf(370): mm_camera_native_control : mode(46), value1(0), value2(0), value3(1)
04-18 10:23:08.323: E/mm-camera(401): mctl_store_curr_target Current target is 0 
04-18 10:23:08.323: E/mm-camera(401): camera_plugin_client_open: plugin client open exit, rc = 0
04-18 10:23:08.323: E/mm-camera-intf(370): mm_camera_open:  opened, break out while loop
```

Comment: Post the logcat output from the crash. And make sure that `anthiasButton` is in `activity_fish.xml`.

Comment: There is nothing in the log you posted that represents the error you mention.

Comment: Thanks codeMagic!!! Somehow I neglected activity_fish.xml and was putting it into the fragment instead. It works now. Thanks